# Evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{e}^{12x}-\mathrm{e}^{-12x}}{\mathrm{e}^{12x}+\mathrm{e}^{-12x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

**My work so far**

$${\displaystyle\int_0^1}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{12x}-\mathrm{e}^{-12x}}{\mathrm{e}^{12x}+\mathrm{e}^{-12x}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

using substitution with $u=\mathrm{e}^{12x}+\mathrm{e}^{-12x}$

$$={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{12u}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

$$=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\dfrac{1}{12}}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

which is the standard integral:

$$=\ln\left(u\right)$$

$$=\dfrac{\ln\left(u\right)}{12}$$

and using substitution with $u=\mathrm{e}^{12x}+\mathrm{e}^{-12x}$

$$=\dfrac{\ln\left(\mathrm{e}^{12x}+\mathrm{e}^{-12x}\right)}{12}+C$$

$$=\dfrac{\ln\left(\mathrm{e}^{-24}\left(\mathrm{e}^{24}+1\right)\right)}{12}-\dfrac{\ln\left(2\right)}{12}+1$$

which is rewritten as

$$\dfrac{\ln\left(\mathrm{e}^{-24}\left(\mathrm{e}^{24}+1\right)\right)-\ln\left(2\right)+12}{12}$$

Is my work correct so far? Also, I thought I was done at the last step, but I noticed this integral can be approximated to $0.9422377349564838$. How would I go about doing this part?

Comment: Looks good so far, desmos or Wolfram alpha are good ways to do evaluation.

Comment: Note: The integrand is $\tanh(12x)$.

Comment: @abiessu Many thanks for that. Would using Desmos or Wolfram Alpha be the only way to approximate the integral? Or, could the 0.9422377349564838 figure be calculated using a specific method?

Comment: Your aswer is correct.

Comment: You could use a numeric method with a calculator (or by hand...), but typically I would expect that a direct calculation of the whole expression would suffice.

Comment: @Laufen You can do anything that Wolfram Alpha does by hand, it might just take you a very long time ;)

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch hah, good point! Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Your solution using u subbing is perfect but just ignore the constant C you have definite integral.

Comment: @AliShather Thanks for the clarification regarding the Constant C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to approximate this numerically, we'll have to resort to series

$$\frac{\log \cosh(12)}{12} = \frac{\log\left(\frac{e^{12}+e^{-12}}{2e^{12}}\right)+12}{12} \approx \frac{\log(1-\frac{1}{2})}{12}+1 \approx 1 - \frac{1}{24} - \frac{1}{96}= \frac{91}{96} \sim 0.948$$

You won't need to consider the $e^{-12}$ until you want around $8$ figures of precision.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_0^1\frac{e^{12x}-e^{-12x}}{e^{12x}+e^{-12x}}\ dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{12}\int_0^1\frac{d(e^{12x}+e^{-12x})}{e^{12x}+e^{-12x}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{12}[\ln(e^{12x}+e^{-12x})]_0^1$$
$$=\frac{1}{12}[\ln(e^{12}+e^{-12})-\ln(2)]$$

Comment: That's what he did in the question body.

Comment: well, OP has used substitution and added a constant of integration which unnecessarily complicated computation. I did it in a much simpler way.

Comment: You could have told him to ignore the constant then.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot Thank you for elaborating on the simpler way of calculating this integral. I didn't know that adding a constant complicates it. Good to know going forward!

Answer (score 2):

We [have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions)

$$\frac{e^{ax}-e^{-ax}}{e^{ax}+e^{-ax}}=\frac{\sinh(ax)}{\cosh(ax)}=\tanh(ax)$$

Then the [integral becomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions)

$$\int_0^1 \frac{e^{ax}-e^{-ax}}{e^{ax}+e^{-ax}}dx=\int_0^1\tanh(ax)dx=\left. \frac{\ln(\cosh(ax))}{a}\right|_{x=0}^{x=1}=\frac{\ln(\cosh(a))}{a}$$

With $a=12$ we get

$$\int_0^1 \frac{e^{12x}-e^{-12x}}{e^{12x}+e^{-12x}}dx=\frac{\ln(\cosh(12))}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the limits to

$$\dfrac{\ln\left(\mathrm{e}^{12x}+\mathrm{e}^{-12x}\right)}{12}\bigg|_0^1= \frac1{12}\ln\frac{e^{12}+e^{-12}}{2}=\frac1{12}\ln \cosh12
$$